# Moving least squares fitting for point displacements having issues

Tags: matlab, least-squares

Explanation of the problem:
I have points with (x,y,z) coordinates at two+ distinct times. For convenience, they can be imagined as irregularly spaced points along the surface of an inverted paraboloid.
There is some minimal thickness to the paraboloid. The paraboloid changes shape slightly as time proceeds (like a balloon inflating) and when it does so, all of the points move.
By substracting the coordinates at time2 - time1, I can get the displacement vectors at each point.

It is important to note (and I suspect this might be the source of the problem) that at the first time point, the x and y coordinates range from 0 to 2000, and the z coordinates are all within a narrower range - say 350 to 450. During the deformation, each point has an x component of displacement, y component, and z component.
The x and y components are small (~50 at most), while the z component is the largest (goes up to 400 near the center, much less near the edges).

Using weighted moving least squares at the location of each point, I am trying to fit the components of displacements to a second degree polynomial surface in terms of the original x,y,z coordinates of the point: eg.
x component of

```
displacement = ax^2 + bxy + cx + dy^2.. + hz^2 + iz + j
```

I use the `lsqr` function in MATLAB,like so, looping through each point for each time interval:

```
Ux = displacements{k,1}(:,1);
Cx = lsqr((adjust_B_matrix'*W*adjust_B_matrix),(adjust_B_matrix'*W*Ux),1e-7,10000);
```

`W` is the weight matrix, and `adjust_B_matrix` is the matrix of all (x,y,z) coordinates at time 1, shifted so that they're all centered around the point at which I'm trying to fit the function.

What is going wrong?
It's just not working -- once I have the functions, they're re-centered around the actual coordinates of the points.
But once I plot the resulting points (initial pointx + displacementx, initial pointy + displacementy, initial pointz + displacementz) by plugging in the coordinates at time 1 into the now-discovered functions, it just spits out a surface that looks just like the surface at time 1.

What might be going wrong? Things I have tried:

1. It's not an issue with the code itself- I generated 'fake' data using a grid of points and it worked perfectly. The predicted locations were superimposed with the actual coordinates and I was able to get back the function I started with. But in my trial example, I used x,y,z from 0 to 5, evenly spaced.
2. Global fitting works (but I need local fitting...).
   I tried MATLAB's curve fitting toolbox and just tried to fit one of the displacements to only x and y coordinates, globally. It worked perfectly.
3. I *think* I shouldn't have a singular matrix issue because I use a large radius (around 75-80) points in the calculations, somewhat dispersed in 3D space.

Suspicions:
I think it has to do with the uneven distribution of initial (x,y,z) coordinates, but I don't know why or how to fix the issue, or even what method I can use.

If you read this far, thank you so much. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Figure for reference:
green = predicted points at time 2. Overlapping mostly with red, the actual coordinates of the points at time 1.
blue is the correct coordinates of points at time 2 (this is where the green ones *should* be if things were working).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKLIQ.png)

Updated link for files:
http://a.tmp.ninja/eWfkNmFZyTFk.zip
Contents - code, sample data (please load the .mat files).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You've obviously put effort into describing this tricky problem, but it's hard to really understand. I think you're much more likley to get help if you could share code that we could run along with example data (see [mcve]). I appreciate that's tricky but for this kind of question I think it will be the best way to get a helpful answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response and the edits! I was worried that the code was too long (I'm a beginner and it shows...) but I'll try to clean it up and post it shortly. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't actually access the code you posted, so here's some general suggestions.

It does look like the curve fitting toolbox has tools that do exactly what you are looking for, checkout the bottom of this page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/polynomial.html#bt9ykh.

It looks like for whatever your learned function for the displacement is just very small or zero everywhere. I suspect the issue is just a minor typo/error on your part somewhere in your pipeline, possibly translating what you have to work with the fit function will reveal the issue.

This really shouldn't be the issue, but in the future if you had much more unbalanced data you could normalize it all before fitting (x_norm = (x - x_mu)/x_std).

Also, I don't think this is your problem either, but you can check if your matrix is close to singular by checking the condition number using the cord() function. So you could check cond(adjust_B_matrix'*W*adjust_B_matrix). Second, If you check the documentation for lsqr there is an option to get a debug return flag, that is worth checking too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I just checked the link, could you perhaps try again if you have time? http://a.tmp.ninja/eWfkNmFZyTFk.zip 
Thank you also for the suggestions -- the thing about the curve fitting toolbox is that I wasn't able to figure out how to perform moving weighted least squares fitting rather than a global fit. There is a spot for weights in the toolbox, but I'm not sure how to have a different set of weights for each fit based on the distance of the neighbors from the point of interest.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the learned function being really small. I have no idea why -- at the very least, for the z displacement, it should be giving me large values. 

I'll check out the debug return flag and the cord function - thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, how can I fit 4D data with the curve fitting toolbox? I need to fit displacement as a function of (x,y,z)